# Overriding CSS in a child of the WordPress TwentyTen theme not taking effect

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I'm having my first stab at creating a child theme, using the Twenty Ten theme as a template (I know it's a bit old now, but the tutorial I am following uses this.) The first thing my tutorial does is change the background colours of the main elements in the theme, to highlight where the DIVs are. I have followed this like so:

```
#wrapper { background: blue; }
#header { background: yellow; }
#main { background: red; }
#container { background: green; }
#primary { background: aqua; }
#footer { background: gold; }
```

When I save the file, all of the colour changes take effect except that of the wrapper id:

[image: screen capture]

I was wondering if this might have anything to do with the fact that the parent theme's style.css seems to have two IDs for wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
}
#wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

I must confess, I don't understand the significance of having two IDs with the same name, but is there any possibility that my child style.css is overriding the first wrapper in the parent's CSS and then the parent's second ID is setting the colour back to white?

If this is the case, how could I tell my CSS file to target the second ID, not the first. If it's not this, does anyone have any suggestions for what it might be?

*Edit: I just want to point out that I have tried changing the color call directly in the parent theme and this produces the desired effect!*

Comment: Two same #wrapper isn't a problem at all in CSS. I think your `#wrapper { background: blue; }` is already applied, but covered by other background colors. Try removing some of them, i.e. `#main { /* background: red; */ }` and see.

Comment: Thanks @sdcr - to save some time on that I have just commented out everything and there is still no blue. I should have mentioned before (and have just added into the question) that if I change the color call in the parent theme's style.css it works as it should.

Comment: Well, that sounds very strange, what if you do `#wrapper { border: 10px solid blue; }` and see.

Comment: Actually, I've been playing around with it and nothing I do to the #wrapper id take effect in the child theme. I've even copied the entirety of the code block for the wrapper and tweaked it, just to be sure. Still nothing. It's like it doesn't want me to override it for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I'm making some progress. I had been using the 'add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');' in my functions.php, as recommended on the WP website. Out of curiosity I switched back to the @import statement in the CSS and now it works. Any idea why this might be? But otherwise, I guess it's all working now.

Comment: Glad your found the solution. Yep, that's the recommended way for adding javascripts and stylesheets. Can say why your previous way only works partly. You can actually post and answer your own question with the field below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to find a partial answer to the problem. Along the way, and with a bit of help from sdcr (in the comments above) I established that actually, no modifications that I was making to the #wrapper id were being taken on board by the child theme, although all other changes were.

Eventually, I tried dropping the following code from my functions.php (although it came recommended by WP):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent_style', 
    get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
}
```

And replacing it with this statement in the CSS:

```
@import url("../twentyten/style.css");
```

Again, WP itself states that this method is now out of date and the first one I mentioned should be used. But using the @import statement fixes the problem, so I guess this will remain a mystery! (At least until I gain a better understanding of the whole process I guess!)